# An equation related to covariance matrix, square root of the matrix, and Euclidean norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

How can I prove this equation:

$${ ({ x }^{ T }\Sigma x) }^{ 1/2 }={ \left\| { \Sigma  }^{ 1/2 }x \right\|  }_{ 2 }$$

In which $\Sigma $ is a covariance matrix. I tried some numerical examples in MATLAB and it seems that this equation is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kinds of operations are may we assume are permissible? I mean, to be perfectly honest, this seems evident, since$$\|\Sigma^{1/2} x\|_2=\sqrt{\|\Sigma^{1/2}x\|_2^2}=\sqrt{\langle\Sigma^{1/2}x,\Sigma^{1/2}x \rangle} =\sqrt{x^T\Sigma^{1/2}\Sigma^{1/2}x}=\sqrt{x^T\Sigma x}.$$
But of course, this assumes you accept the definition of a symmetric matrix square root, the definition of the Euclidean norm as the square root of the inner-product of the vector with itself, etc.

Comment: Oooo... I accept all of these definitions and you are definitely right it's evident. Thanks very much!